# HTML Fails to Reference JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, html

In the `head` of my document, I have two script references:

This is my html code

```
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
  <script src='Newproject\Success.js'></script>
```

In my `Success.js` file, I have the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('hover')
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover')
    )};
)};
```

Despite that I have referenced `Success.js` in my HTML file, the code does not execute.

Comment: Did you import the jquery library?

Comment: Well she did, as you can see from the first link.

Comment: shouldn't it be `src='Newproject/Success.js'>`?

Comment: btw: when referencing files on the server(and urls in general) you _never_ use backslashes, just the good old /.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `)}` to `})`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).addClass('hover')
        },
        function(){
            $(this).removeClass('hover')
        }
    ) // it is }) indeed
});
```

Comment: He's passing two functions into the ``.hover``  jQuery method but ends the parentheses before the end of his second parameter. Right.

Comment: @Crowes Can you use your eyes to watch carefully?

Answer (score 0):

if they are in the same folder then your script src path should just be Success.js

```
<script src='Success.js'></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, this or ``src="/Success.js"``. Your document is looking for the folder `Newproject` with a ``.js`` file in it, whereas the ``.js`` file is at root.